# Can this function be anything but a polynomial function?

Tags: analysis

If $f\in\mathcal{C}^\infty((0,1),\mathbb{R})$ verifies the following:
\begin{equation}
\forall x\in(0,1),\,\exists n\in\mathbb{N},\quad f^{(n)}(x)=0
\end{equation}
Can $f$ be anything but a polynomial function?

Comment: See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial) on MathOverflow.